# How use "display:none" with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="ThanksWebPart" class="ThanksWebPartDisplay">

</div>
```

I want to be able to hide this `<div>` tag. I want to remove `display:none` if I'm on the previous page.
How do I remove `display:none` if I have a different location address?

Comment: [**jQuery toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**With jQuery**, use [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) :

```
$('#ThanksWebPart').toggle();  // toggle again to make it appear again.
```

---

**With Javascript**, use the `style.display` property :

```
getElementById("ThanksWebPart").style.display = 'none'; //'block' to make it appear again.
```

Answer (score 2):

`$("#ThanksWebPart").css("display", "none");` to hide.
`$("#ThanksWebPart").css("display", "block");` to show.

Alternatively, you can also use `.show()` and `.hide()`.